# OpenVPN connection resetting

Tags: openvpn

OpenVPN running on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi Debian, Wheezy).

Relatively stock, didn't do anything other than install OpenVPN, and generated some keys.

Server config:

```
local 192.168.1.175
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/server.crt
key keys/server.key
dh keys/dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth keys/ta.key 0
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 10
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log        /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

Client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote [A_GALAXY_FAR_FAR_AWAY] 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert foo.crt
key foo.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Client Log:

```
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.7 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Jun  8 2015
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015, LZO 2.08
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Sat Jun 27 22:17:19 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Sat Jun 27 22:17:22 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'proxy NONE  '
Sat Jun 27 22:17:23 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Sat Jun 27 22:17:23 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1435465043,RESOLVE,,,
Sat Jun 27 22:17:23 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sat Jun 27 22:17:23 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]67.177.250.212:1194
Sat Jun 27 22:17:23 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1435465043,WAIT,,,
Sat Jun 27 22:18:23 2015 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Sat Jun 27 22:18:23 2015 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Sat Jun 27 22:18:23 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Sat Jun 27 22:18:23 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1435465103,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,
```

I've never really configured OpenVPN before, I'm wondering if I screwed something up.

I have the PI VPN server assigned to a static IP of 192.168.1.175

I'm connecting to it from a local machine on the local network just to test it. But I did try to connect from a place nearby (a Subway I frequent) and it still wouldn't work.

Server ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c6:38:f8
          inet addr:192.168.1.175  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:134472 errors:0 dropped:458 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8010 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10519275 (10.0 MiB)  TX bytes:847593 (827.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:612 (612.0 B)  TX bytes:612 (612.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I haven't set any rules for iptables (which I suspect may be the issue):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I've forwarded port 1194 to 192.168.1.175 (the VPN server) in my router properly, it's visable or at least it was when I tried using the tap over tcp, now I'm trying tun over udp because that's suppose to be easier / better or something.

I don't really know what I'm suppose to do here.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Routing:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         myrouter.local  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         myrouter.local  0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

Forwarding is enabled:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This was commented in the client config:

```
# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
tls-auth ta.key 1
```

I needed the TLS key and obviously this needed to be uncommented.